# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de mantener datos en una sesión c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, session

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación asp.net, mantengo información en variables de sesión para evitar hacer muchas peticiones a la base de datos y poder filtrar los datos desde el contenido de las variables, pero en cuestiones de seguridad no se que tan viable, factible sea seguir utilizando las variables, leí que se pueden usar ViewState u objetos json pero no he utilizado ninguno de estos dos desde el código de c#.

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy abierta, pero desde mi punto de vista si usas stateless, no necesitas sesiones porque preguntas la autorización y la autenticación la haces 1. Preguntando a la base de datos si el hash usado tiene permisos, 2. Le preguntas a otro micro servicio. EN el caso de sesiones puedes crear diccionarios estáticos tipo singleton, pero estos no se pueden replicar fácilmente entre servidores para aplicaciones con alta disponibilidad... puedes ser más claro con un fragmento de código asp-net core?

Answer (score 0):

Pues hay varias formas, pero la que yo utilizo es la siguiente.
Para las sesiones, a mi parecer, lo mejor es utilizar tokens, los cuales tienen datos encriptados de cierta manera para autentificar a los usuarios, entonces cada sesión tiene su propio token con el cual el usuario hace su petición al servidor y si y solo si ese token esta registrado en la DB para ese usuario, el servidor responderá con los datos que solicito el usuario. En el caso de .NET yo utilizo [JWT](https://jwt.io/). Cabe mencionar que deberás implementar el JWT en el Front y en el Back, para codificar y decodificar en ambas direcciones.

Entonces una vez ya tengas tu token en el Front, lo que puedes hacer es encriptar el objeto que quieres guardar con los datos del usuario, ya sea en cookies o LocalStorage, para esto puedes usar datos desencriptados del token que tiene el usuario y otros valores que tu elijas, ya sea un secret-key, etc. De preferencia no uses la cadena de token tal cual, porque seria muy fácil entrar a esos datos. Y la cosa seria que cuando el usuario entre a tu APP desencriptes sus datos temporalmente para que los uses en lo que quieras. Otra cosa que te tengo que mencionar es que el token cambia cada vez que la sesión del usuario expira.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como implementar JWT con .NET [AUTENTICACIÓN JWT USANDO ASP.NET CORE](https://anexsoft.com/autenticacion-jwt-usando-asp-net-core),[Angular 8 JWT](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/22/angular-8-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial), lo que si, no te quedes solo con lo que te pasé, hay muchas y mejores formas, esto es solo un ejemplo.